# ActivityRecord Library class extend model NullPointerException

Tags: android

I am using ActivityRecord(ORM Library) for Android . Whenever using extends Model . I am always get  NullPointerException. Is there any solution ? Where is my mistake ? Code sample is below. Thanks a lot for helping.

```
01-22 02:08:11.883    7238-7238/main.yurtrehberi.yourmovies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.yurtrehberi.yourmovies/main.yurtrehberi.yourmovies.Ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.activeandroid.Cache.getTableInfo(Cache.java:148)
        at com.activeandroid.Model.<init>(Model.java:54)
        at main.yurtrehberi.yourmovies.Database.Model.Movie.<init>(Movie.java:11)
        at main.yurtrehberi.yourmovies.Ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Model model = new Movie();
}
```

Movie Class:

```
@Table(name = "Movies")
public class Movie extends Model {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error appears to be originating from within your `Movie` class. What does this class look like and what specifically is on line 11?

Comment: I added Movie class.

Comment: Can you add your `Model` class to the post? Is line 44 inside your MainActivity this: `Model model = new Movie();`?

Comment: yes i added main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Notice also that **the application name points to the ActiveAndroid application class. This step is required for ActiveAndroid to work**. If you already point to a custom Application class, just make that class a subclass of com.activeandroid.app.Application."

```
<manifest ...>
    <application android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application" ...>
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also you need to add the com.android.support:support-v4 library to the dependencies of your project.